# Woocommerce "filter by attributes" are not showing in any archive page

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, lookup-tables

Im only able to show "filter by price" " filter by brand"but I can't get "by size" or "by color"

i have to mention that my products and variation are coming from my ERP via woo API
if someone can help even with some fees please let me know

I tried to regenerate the attributes lookup tables from tools tab (i have more than 2200 products) including
i changed the theme to default and many other themes
i tried disable all plugins except woocommerce
i delete .htaccess and saved the permalinks again
I cleared the cache and disabled / delete the cache plugin

Comment: Provide more information. Is your attribute counting properly in your admin ? Lets say you have 100 products with red color is your attribute counted and showing 100 ?

Comment: Also go and clear from Woo -> Status -> Tools any transients etc.

Comment: I already cleared transient many times but actually the count is not showing in the admin> products> attributes > size

Comment: I can give access so you can check

Comment: Guys, its almost 1 year and i couldn't solve my problem, the "terms count" are all zero and accordingly the "filter  by attributes" is not showing on shop pages... i have run the "recount terms" but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your attributes are actually specified in your products.
Filter options don't show if they are not specified anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem, products created with REST API, the products with their variations show on woocommerce as if I had manually created them and the attributes.  Under Attributes, the attributes and their terms are also showing, but if I click on colour a list of the terms is shown and next to every colour it shows 0, even though each colour exists as a product attribute and also a variation.

If I create a new variable product manually and use the attributes to create variations then the numbers appear next to the terms, but the filters on the website don't work.

For everything to be perfect I have to create the attributes manually and create the products manually (workaround).

Comment: exactly same here, but i have more than 5000 products with variations of size and colors, no way i can do manually